# i want to set typeface for GridView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want to set typeface for TextView which is the adapter of GridView. i need to access typeface from Asset folder.

```
TextView listitem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listitem);
listitem.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "DroidSans4.ttf"));
```

I'm facing this list of errors.

```
> 
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andro.sqllite/com.andro.sqllite.UsingSQLiteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at com.andro.sqllite.UsingSQLiteActivity.onCreate(UsingSQLiteActivity.java:92)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-01 14:38:54.510: E/AndroidRuntime(9088):     ... 11 more
```

At this line of code i'm facing these error:

```
listitem.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "DroidSans4.ttf"));
```

Can anyone guide me how do i set typeface for my GridView? Or Guide me in this regard?

Comment: What is SQLiteActivity? Have you copied the font in Asset folder?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't call `setContentView` before `TextView listitem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listitem);`

Answer (score 0):

R.id.listitem is the layout of the grid items? If so you need to set the typeface in the getView() method of your adapter and not in onCreate. During onCreate() no grid items are created yet. Thats why findById returns null resulting in the NPE. Post the code of your adapter if you need more help.

Comment: yes its a layout of gridview which is only a textview. Your point is valid and this is exactly what i need. Can you please give me a piece of code to set the typeface by getView()?

Comment: What adapter are you using? SimpleCursorAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this,

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/BPreplay.otf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code to apply typeface...but first you need to copy appropriate font (which you need) in to your asset/font folder.

```
TextView listitem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listitem);
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
listitem.setTypeface(font);
listitem.setText("जहां आप जाना चाहते हैं");
```

Comment: this listitem is the gridview adapter. it's not helpfull.